# Division using GMP's low-level API

Tags: c++, c, biginteger, gmp, integer-division

I'm using GMP's low-level interface (`mpn_`, see https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions) to do some fixed-size 192 bit (three limb) integer calculations.

Currently I am trying to divide one random uint192 by another random uint192 and fail to select the right function. There are multiple candidates:

- `mpn_tdiv_qr` - Documentation says "most significant limb of the divisor must be non-zero"
- `mpn_divrem` - Documentation says "obsolete"
- `mpn_divrem_1` - Takes a single limb as a divisor
- `mpn_divexact_1` - Documentation says "expecting ... to divide exactly"

So there is an obsolete function (`mpn_divrem`), a function that takes small (<= 64bit) divisors only (`mpn_divrem_1`), one that has undefined behavior with remainders (`mpn_divexact_1`) and one that takes large (>= 129bit) divisors only (`mpn_tdiv_qr`).

I tried `mpn_tdiv_qr` since I thought I'm misunderstanding the documentation and because it replaces the obsolete function. But it actually crashes when most significant limb is zero.

Did I miss something? How can I divide two random 3-limb-numbers? Or numbers with a divisor of 65..128 non-zero bits (e.g. `0xffffffff'ffffffffffffffff'ffffffffffffffff / 0xff'ffffffffffffffff`)?

Comment: There may not be 1 function that does everything you want, this is low level, you may need to test first if the numerator is smaller than the denominator (quotient is 0), then what the true size of the denominator is (2 if only the first limb is 0, 1, for 2 0 limbs, and don't call anything for a division by 0), etc. Reading the code for the mpz functions could also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solution is simple: Instead of passing the number of allocated limbs to `mpn_tdiv_qr` pass the number of limbs minus the number of leading zero limbs of the divisor instead. E.g. when using 3 limbs and a concrete divisor has `limb[2] == 0`, `limb[1] != 0` and `limb[0] == 0` a `2` is passed for the divisor length. This way it is guaranteed that the most significant limb (in this case `[1]`) is non-zero.